# Vue 3 data not retreactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, reactive

i've been trying to upgrade from Vue 2 to 3 for months and I'm having trouble with a data property not being reactive. The parent component has this:

```
<component
      :class="parentBlock.blockType"
      v-model="parentBlock"
      :is="getType(parentBlock.blockType)"
      :context="context"
    />
```

The child component has a `block` data property that gets updated by a 3rd party. The block successfully updates within the child in the `updateImage()` and then the watch fires and emits to the parent, parent updates the parentBlock and it successfully updates down to the child. The `modelValue` in the child is updated but the block resets to the old value and for the life of me, I have no idea why. I have tried using a watch on modelValue but Vue throws a lot of errors in the console.

```js
<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'RWImage',
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: [Array, Object],
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.block = reactive(this.modelValue);
  },
  watch: {
    block: {
      deep: true,
      // immediate: true,
      handler(newVal) {
        // The newVal is right. This emits up to the parent which updates that
        // modelValue and comes back down to this child where the block gets updated with the 
        // old value. However if you use the vue tools, the modelValue is right. Just this
        // keeps hanging on to old value even though it updated down in updatedImage(). 
        this.$emit('update:modelValue', newVal);
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      block: {}
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // EventBus is using mitt. Asset Chosen gets fired when the block gets changed using a
    // 3rd party plugin. This gets fired properly.
    EventBus.on('asset-chosen', this.updateImage);
  },
  method: {
    updateImage(data) {
      if (this.$.uid === data.uid) {
        this.block = Object.assign({}, this.block, {
          src: data.asset.secure_url,
          cloudinaryId: data.asset.public_id,
          cloudinary: data.asset,
        })

        // Right here, the block is updated properly. This fires the watch.
        console.log(this.block);
      }
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Has anyone ran into it where the a data property resets? I'm so confused.
Thanks!

Comment: instead of `this.block = Object.assign({}, this.block, { .....` wouldn't you do `Object.assign(this.block, { .....` - not sure if that's your issue though

Comment: `NOTE this is actually Vue 3` ... so why did you attempt to write a snippet using vue 2.5.17?

Comment: If you're going to use `reactive` function you should try switching to Composition API, which is what it's meant for. I've never seen Options/Composition API mixed this way and may be a source of trouble.  If you're going to stay with older Options API, you should use computed getter/setter like how you would've done in Vue 2. This will mean not having to watch and/or mutate `this.block` **and** emitting to the parent. You will only have to emit.

Comment: @JaromandaX The code snippet doesn't have Vue 3 as an option. Sorry.

Comment: @yoduh I've used reactive in the data in other components and it was fine. I really think it was the created part that was causing it to refresh to outdated data.

Comment: So what? you didn't write anything that could even be close to actually running

Comment: `// NOTE this is actually Vue 3` should've said `// NOTE this wont run regardless of vuejs version, so I made it into a runnable code snippet loading the incorrect vue version so that it still won't run`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see here, you're creating a reactive object in the `created` using `this.block = reactive(this.modelValue)`, but you're also declaring `block` in the `data`. This could be causing a conflict because vue 3 might be treating `block` as a **non-reactive** property.

So, you should remove the `block` from the *data(){ return{..} }*.

```
data() {
   return {
      block: {} //<-- remove this
   };
},
```

And only use the reactive `block` in the `created`.

```
<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue'

export default {
 name: 'RWImage',
 props: {
   modelValue: {
     type: [Array, Object],
   }
 },
 created() {
   this.block = reactive(this.modelValue); //<-- use this only
 },
 watch: {
   block: {
     deep: true,
     handler(newVal) {
       this.$emit('update:modelValue', newVal);
     },
   },
 },
 mounted() {
   EventBus.on('asset-chosen', this.updateImage);
 },
 methods: {
   updateImage(data) {
     if (this.$.uid === data.uid) {
       this.block = Object.assign({}, this.block, {
         src: data.asset.secure_url,
         cloudinaryId: data.asset.public_id,
         cloudinary: data.asset,
       })
       console.log(this.block);
     }
   },
 }
}
</script>
```

Also, I notice that you wrote `method:` instead of `methods:`, correct it as this could cause additional issue.

## Edit

Additional: Cause of issue might due to use of the `reactive()` in `created()`. This is part of vue 3's Composition API and is not typically used in the Options API, which you're using in the component. It is used to create a reactive object, and it should be used in the `setup()` not in `created()`. Then, you're trying to make the `modelValue` prop reactive, but you're doing it in the `created()` which is not the correct place to do it.

Instead, as advise by @yoduh, you should use a `computed` property with a `getter` and a `setter`.

```
computed: {
   block: {
     get() {
       return this.modelValue;
     },
     set(newVal) {
       this.$emit('update:modelValue', newVal);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: how familiar are you with Vue? because `this.block` refers to the `block` defined in `data`.  It's not a conflict.  See the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data) on the data option.

Comment: Yes, but the way vue.js handles reactivity can cause some confusion. When assign a new value to a property in the data of v2, it automatically makes that property reactive. This means that vue.js will automatically update the DOM whenever that property changes.

Comment: While in v3, the reactivity system has been re-written and is now based on the proxy object. This means that it can detect changes to properties of objects, but only if those properties were reactive to begin with. When assign a new value to a reactive property, v3 will automatically update the DOM to reflect those changes, but if assign a new value to a property that was not reactive, v3 will not be able to detect the change and will not update the DOM accordingly.

Comment: You're slightly incorrect about Vue 2's reactivity system, [it could not detect property additions/deletions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects). Between the two, Vue 3 reactivity has less caveats. Regardless, as long as `block` is defined in `data`, it is reactive.  that's how Options API, which OP is using, has always worked and continues to work in Vue 3 even though the underlying reactivity system has changed.  I actually advise the opposite, to not use `reactive` function, as it's meant for Composition API.  OP should use a computed getter/setter.

Comment: Agreed. I edit the answer. Thank you.

Comment: That was it! Using the get/set on computed was the answer. Man this was killing my head yesterday. Really appreciate the feedback!!